# How to control the velocity and position of a point when calculating Newton's law of gravitation?

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to build a function that will calculate Newton's law of gravitation (G*M/r^2) of an object for a given timestep while being able to change the position and velocity of that point.

As an example I will try to show what I have done to set the initial velocity and starting position of a point (I will however at some point need to be able to display the point in real-time and move it around while the loops are running).

I have written two examples that try to demonstrate the trouble I am having.

If you look closely at the plot you might notice that those two lines don't overlap (even though all starting params were the same).

**This plot shows when all starting params = 0**
[image]

**printed output:**

Concept 1 *(calculated intervals = 1 second)*:

```
v:9.82  pos:9.82
v:19.64 pos:29.46
v:29.46 pos:58.93
v:39.28 pos:98.22
```

Concept 2 *(calculated intervals = 1 second)*:

```
v:0.0   pos:0.0  
v:9.82  pos:4.91
v:19.64 pos:19.64
v:29.46 pos:44.20
```

According to this [online calculator](http://www.gravitycalc.com/) it indicates Concept1 is incorrect, and Concept2 is very close to actual.

The code below plots both examples. And I have added two variables that allow for setting the `initial_velocity` and `initial_position` (*please see the additional two plot images below for details*).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = 6.67408 * 10 ** -11  # Newton meters^2/kg^2
Me = 5.9736 * 10 ** 24  # mass of earth in kg
Re = 6.371 * 10 ** 6  # radius of earth in meters

def get_g(mass, distance, seconds):
    _g = G * mass / distance ** 2
    _d = (_g * (seconds ** 2)) / 2
    _v = _g * seconds
    return _v, _d, _g

def Concept1(seconds=1, timestep=0.1):
    plt_x = np.linspace(0, seconds, (seconds/timestep))
    plt_y = np.zeros_like(plt_x)

    """
    Simple concept demonstrating values that are very close to actual.

    Time =  0.1  vel =  0.9822280588290989  pos =  0.049111402941454954  _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.2  vel =  1.9644561176581978  pos =  0.19644561176581982   _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.3  vel =  2.946684176487297   pos =  0.44200262647309463   _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.4  vel =  3.9289122353163957  pos =  0.7857824470632793    _g =  9.822280588290988
    """

    for _i in range(len(plt_y)):
        t = (_i+1)
        _v, _d, _g = get_g(Me, Re, t*timestep)

        plt_y[_i] = _d
        #print("Time = ", t*timestep, " vel = ", _v, " pos = ", _d, " _g = ", _g)

    return plt_x,plt_y

def Concept2(seconds=1, timestep=0.1, initial_velocity=0, initial_position=0):

    plt_x = np.linspace(0, seconds, seconds/timestep)
    plt_y = np.zeros_like(plt_x, dtype=np.float32)

    """
    Dynamic concept showing variable velocity and starting position (output is not accurate)

    Time =  0.1  vel =  0.9822280588290989  pos =  0.0982228058829099  _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.1  vel =  1.9644561176581978  pos =  0.2946684176487297  _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.1  vel =  2.9466841764872966  pos =  0.5893368352974594  _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.1  vel =  3.9289122353163957  pos =  0.982228058829099   _g =  9.822280588290988
    """

    vel = initial_velocity * timestep
    pos = initial_position

    for _i in range(len(plt_y)):
        t = timestep
        _v, _d, _g = get_g(Me, Re, t)

        vel += _g * timestep
        pos += vel * timestep

        plt_y[_i] = pos
        #print("Time = ", t, " vel = ", vel, " pos = ", pos, " _g = ", _g)

    return plt_x, plt_y

def Concept3(seconds=1, timestep=0.1, initial_velocity=0, initial_position=0):

    plt_x = np.linspace(0, seconds, seconds/timestep)
    plt_y = np.zeros_like(plt_x, dtype=np.float32)

    """
    Dynamic concept showing variable velocity and starting position (output is accurate)

    Time =  0.1  vel =  0.982228058829099   pos =  0.049111402941454954  _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.1  vel =  1.964456117658198   pos =  0.19644561176581982   _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.1  vel =  2.9466841764872975  pos =  0.44200262647309463   _g =  9.822280588290988
    Time =  0.1  vel =  3.928912235316396   pos =  0.7857824470632793    _g =  9.822280588290988
    """

    vel = initial_velocity * timestep
    pos = initial_position
    gforce = 0

    for _i in range(len(plt_y)):
        t = timestep

        _v, _d, _g = get_g(Me, Re, t)

        vel += (gforce + _g)*timestep**2/2
        pos += vel
        gforce = _g

        plt_y[_i] = pos
        #print("Time = ", t, " vel = ", (vel + _d)/timestep, " pos = ", pos, " _g = ", gforce)

    return plt_x, plt_y


seconds=1
timestep=0.1
initial_velocity = 0
initial_position = 0
x1, y1 = Concept1(seconds=seconds, timestep=timestep)
x2, y2 = Concept2(seconds=seconds, timestep=timestep, initial_velocity=initial_velocity, initial_position=initial_position)
x3, y3 = Concept3(seconds=seconds, timestep=timestep, initial_velocity=initial_velocity, initial_position=initial_position)

plt.xlabel("Time (Seconds)")
plt.ylabel("Distance")
plt.plot(x1, y1,'g', label='Concept 1 (gauge)')
plt.plot(x2, y2,'b', label='Concept 2')
plt.plot(x3, y3,'r', label='Concept 3')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I am relatively new to physics (and this is a learning experience). I have been wondering if possibly my approach is incorrect. And if so I really would like to learn more about how to accomplish this. All suggestions will be gladly noted. And thank you!

**Plot showing initial_velocity = 2000**
[image: Initial Velocity]

**Plot showing initial_position = 100000**
[image: Initial position]

[UPDATE]

Added a Concept3 to the code.

I "think" it achieves what I needed by storing the current gforce value in a variable for each loop iteration.

I then add it to the current gforce value and divide that by 2.
After which I update the current velocity.

Here's the output after making the alterations (*seconds=1 timestep=0.1*):
[image: Comparison of dist/time with initial velocity and positon]

Comment: What is your question? Is it a programming question or a physics question?

Comment: After a short reading of your code, it looks that the main difference between concept1 and concept2 is that in concept1 you start at timestep 1 while in concept2 you start at timestep 0. I think that the differences could come from position and velocities not taken at the same time...